# PATINDEX all values of a column

Tags: sql-server, patindex

I'm making a query that will delete all rows from table1 that has its column table1.id = table2.id

table1.id column is in nvarchar(max) with an xml format like this:

```
<customer><name>Paulo</name><gender>Male</gender><id>12345</id></customer>
```

**EDIT:**
The id column is just a part of a huge XML so the ending tag may not match the starting tag.

I've tried using name.nodes but it only applies to xml columns and changing the column datatype is not a choice, So far this is the my code using `PATINDEX`

```
DELETE t1
FROM table1 t1
WHERE PATINDEX('%12345%',id) != 0
```

But what I need is to search for all values from table2.id which contains like this:

```
12345
67890
10000
20000
30000
```

Any approach would be nice like sp_executesql and/or while loop, or is there a better approach than using patindex? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select *
--Delete A
 From Table1 A
 Join Table2 B on CharIndex('id>'+SomeField+'<',ID)>0
```

I don't know the name of the field in Table2.  I am also assuming it is a varchar.  If not, `cast(SomeField as varchar(25))`

> **EDIT - This is what I tested.  It should work**

```
Declare @Table1 table (id varchar(max))
Insert Into @Table1 values
('<customer><name>Paulo</name><gender>Male</gender><id>12345</id></customer>'),
('<customer><name>Jane</name><gender>Femail</gender><id>7895</id></customer>')

Declare @Table2 table (SomeField varchar(25))
Insert into @Table2 values
('12345'),
('67890'),
('10000'),
('20000'),
('30000')


Select *
--Delete A
 From @Table1 A
 Join @Table2 B on CharIndex('id>'+SomeField+'<',ID)>0
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it seems to work fine but I need to get all the IDs in table2.id. It is like 3000+ IDs in there. In your code, we declare the IDs in here: `('12345,67890,10000,20000,30000',',')`. Sorry for the poor english.

Comment: Do you have a table or query which generates the 3000+ ids?

Comment: @Cyberpau Sorry, I just saw the list was in table 2... one moment

Comment: Yes. I have a "IDs to delete" table with 3000+ ids. I want to delete all the rows from table1 with ids from the "IDs to delete table"

Comment: It returns no result. I tried to cast it to nvarchar because my column is in nvarchar but still no result.

Comment: @Cyberpau see my EDIT

Comment: I've tried your code and it really works! but I don't know why does it returns zero on my tables. I did exactly what I needed to do but still no results.

Comment: @Cyberpau try this CharIndex(SomeField,ID)>0   it will be less precise

Comment: @Cyberpau what is the field name in table2?

Comment: When I copy a value of table2.ID then paste it, it gives 1234<tab><tab>. But when I copy other column it doesn't give <tab>s or white spaces. I think that affects the query.

The field name in table2 is ID. Ive already tried removing >< and still no results.

Comment: @Cyberpau sounds like table2 needs to be cleaned up.  Update Table2 Set ID = ltrim(rtrim(Replace(Replace(ID,char(9),''),' ','')))

Comment: It works now. I used
`Select * From @Table1 A Join @Table2 B on CharIndex('id>'+RTRIM(LTRIM(ID))+'<',ID)>0`

Comment: @Cyberpau Well done.  That was harder than it should have been :)  cheers

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
;with cteBase as (
    Select *,XMLData=cast(id as xml) From Table1
)
Select *
 From cteBase
 Where XMLData.value('(customer/id)[1]','int') in (12345,67890,10000,20000,30000)
```

If you are satisfied with the results, change the final  `Select *` to `Delete`

Comment: Thank you so much. But unfortunately my id column is not a complete XML format. It is only a part of a huge XML so it throws an error:

`XML parsing: line 1, character 27, end tag does not match start tag` 

Is there any other way using `PATINDEX`?